# Am I right about this definition of submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, definition

Consider the following [definition of submanifold](https://books.google.com/books?id=rj04AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> 1.5.  $\ \bf Definition.\ $ A subset $M\subset\mathbf R^{n}$ is called a $\underline{\text{differentiable submanifold}}$ of $\mathbf R^n$ of $\underline{\text{dimension}}$ $m\leqslant n$, if to each $x\in M$ there corresponds an invertible germ $\widetilde{\phi}\colon (\mathbf R^n,x)\to(\mathbf R^n,0)$, such that $\widetilde{\phi}(M,x)=(\mathbf R^m,x)\subset(\mathbf R^n,x)$ ($\mathbf R^m$ linearly imbedded in $\mathbf R^n$ for $m\leqslant n$)

It seems to me that this is not equivalent to the usual definition of a submanifold: the usual definition is that $M$ is a submanifold of $N$ if there is a map $f: M \to N$ such that $f$ is a smooth injective embedding that is a homeomorphism onto its image.

As far as I can tell the definition above merely says that $M$ comes with an atlas consisting of smooth diffeomorphisms $\phi$. But then any subset $M$ of $\mathbb R^n$ that can be endowed with such an atlas would be a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.

> Am I missing something? Please could someone clarify this to me?

Comment: to be more precise, I think the definition you write here amounts to saying $M$ is an $m$-slice in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main kinds of submanifolds:

- embedded submanifolds (also called regular) have subspace topology. Appear as images of smooth embeddings. Charts on these submanifolds can be made by setting some unused coordinates to constants.
- immersed submanifolds do not necessarily have the subspace topology. Appear as images of smooth immersions. For example, the [dense curve on torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus). There is no way the chart on the dense curve can be obtained by restricting a chart on the torus.

See [submanifold article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold), or much better, see Chapters 4 and 5 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. I think the definition you quote amounts to the embedded case. So, I would disagree that $M$ is so free from the topology of the ambient space. In particular, see Theorem 5.8 on page 101 of Lee's text where he explains that the *$k$-slice condition* implies the structure of an **smoothly embedded** submanifold.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realised that there were two types of submanifolds. That really helps to clear up some of my confusion.

Comment: Glad to be of help, best wishes with your studies. Btw, if you don't have Lee's text already it is worth the money..